# How to listen to AWS SQS messages on Flask app start?

Tags: flask, listener, boto3, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a `Flask` application which needs to do some operations on the messages that it receives from `AWS SQS`. I've mimiced `SQS` using `Docker` container and `boto3` library.

But what I'm not able to figure out is how to start receiving messages as soon as the `Flask app` is started.

What is the better way to listen to the messages from `SQS` queue? I've tried creating a view function that starts listening to `SQS` messages when a specific endpoint is hit. But I'm not able to hit the endpoint after the flask app is started.

Please let me know if there is any better approach to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this (the one I favor) is to run a separate process that listens to SQS, forwarding messages to the Flask app via HTTP.

The other approach is to run both the Flask app and the SQS listener as separate threads within a single process. That's doable, but is much more complex.

Comment: I understand you mean having something like a lambda in AWS that posts to a Flask “/receive” route, right? When dealing with reasonable amount of messages (say 50-100 coming every 5-10 seconds or so), and a not so fast processing, wouldn’t the server break? Currently I’ve been working with a thread, but would like to move to a more sustainable (and easy to maintain) option... Thanks!

Comment: If you use a wsgi server (e.g., gunicorn, uwsgi) to deploy your app, you can (within available resources) arrange for multiple processes running the Flask app, and even enable multiple threads. How many you'll need depends on what "no so fast" means.

Comment: thanks, currently using uWSGI. My processing can take up to 10-20seconds for each message. So not too sure how powerful the server would need to be (CPU and RAM wise) to allow that many processes/threads. Imagine this would put a heavy load on the server...